# How can you implement a React component in Rust?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rust

I want to implement a React component using Rust. That component should react to the React life-cycle, I need to know when it's mounted for instance

```js
import React from "react";
import MyRustComponent from "my-rust-library";

export default MyApp = ({mountRustComponent}) => {
  return mountRustComponent ? <MyRustComponent /> : <div />
}
```

Now I would like to know in my implementation of `MyRustComponent` when the component has been mounted.

I only see two ways to do this:

1. Either inherit `MyRustComponent` from  `React.Component`
2. Integrate react hooks, namely `React.useEffect` into Rust

I don't know how to do either of those things.

The first options seems to be easier, but I would have to bridge the `React.Component` to Rust. For `React.useEffect` there would also have to be some bridging, but it may be harder ton actually use that hook in Rust it seems to me.

Are there other options? Is it even possible to implement a React Component in Rust?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this: Can you elaborate on your reasons? Do you maybe have a question why I am posting this?

Comment: `Is it even possible to implement a React Component in Rust?` Unless I'm missing something fundamental here, then it's obviously not possible. React is a JavaScript library, so you can only write a component in JS. Or is there some way to get Rust to compile into JavaScript? (I know you can to WebAssembly, but that isn't the same as JS.)

Comment: You can call WebAssembly that was generated from Rust from a react component, but the React component itself has to be built in React.

Comment: So yes, WebAssembly. Also in Node you can write a native node extension and bridge that to JS, which is what I intend to do. I know this all sounds crazy, but I want to bridge React to Skia so you can implement cross platform applications with node js like react-native, just using Skia, like Flutter is.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Why do you say the React Component has to be built in React? Do you mean JS? To the JS runtime, there is no difference between a function implemented in JS an and a function implemented with WebAssembly

Comment: Of course there is a difference between a function in WebAssembly and JS

Comment: Can you elaborate? The way I understand WebAssembly, if you expose a function to the JavaScript runtime, accept the proper arguments and return the values and recognize the underlying types, the JavaScript runtime accepts it the same way it would accept a function implemented in JS

Comment: (Apart from that, my use-case is a native node extension)

Answer (score 0):

There is [Yew](https://yew.rs/) : https://yew.rs/
wich try to implement React component's concept and with Jsx like , with this kind of syntax ... :

```
#[function_component(App)]
fn app() -> Html {
// ...
 let selected_video = use_state(|| None);

 let on_video_select = {
     let selected_video = selected_video.clone();
     Callback::from(move |video: Video| {
         selected_video.set(Some(video))
     })
 };

 let details = selected_video.as_ref().map(|video| html! {
     <VideoDetails video={video.clone()} />
 });

html! {
    <>
        <h1>{ "RustConf Explorer" }</h1>
        <div>
            <h3>{"Videos to watch"}</h3>
            <VideosList videos={videos} on_click={on_video_select.clone()} />
        </div>
         <div>
             <h3>{ "John Doe: Building and breaking things" }</h3>
             <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x360.png?text=Video+Player+Placeholder" alt="video thumbnail" />
         </div>
     </>
}
}
```